# DSAS cannot find database table for baseline layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, personal-geodatabase, digital-shoreline-analysis-system

I am trying to calculate change statistics using a baseline and shorelines for 5 years in DSAS VERSION 4.4. The default parameters, transect casting stages go well and there is no trouble in detecting baselines and shorelines, but while calculating change statistics, the error message:

> unable to find database table for baseline layer 'baseline'

pops up as shown in the screenshot image below.

Could anybody guide me on this?

[image]

Comment: Personal geodatabase (Access) is an archaic format. Have you tried using file geodatabase?

Comment: DSAS requires its inputs to be managed within a personal geodatabase

Comment: I notice your PGDB is stored in a folder called "New Folder" - try moving to a folder without a space.  I have seen, on occasion, some third-party tools fail when they can't handle spaces in folder or file names

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the geodatabase format from .gdb to .mdb. Ahhhh the stupidity. This is not even documented. It feels a lot that ArcMap never came out of the eighties, working a lot like Windows 3.1. At least it seems that ArcGIS Pro will change things to the better, at last.

See the right procedure here "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lzpHdm4mdg".

It works also for DSAS version 5.0.

Comment: ArcMap never *entered* the eighties -- 8.0.1 wasn't released until after Y2K. ArcGIS Pro doesn't support personal geodatabase at all.