# Unable to find database table for baseline layer: data integrity issue(s) encountered during calculation of Rates in DSAS

Tags: digital-shoreline-analysis-system, mdb

[image]

I am facing data integrity issues during calculation of rates, after successfully creating Transect layer. The error reads `Unable to find database table for baseline layer` , here my baseline layer name is `baseline_test1_BSD`. I have attached the screenshots for the problem. If anyone has any solution, please help.
I am using Arcmap 10.8 with DSAS v5 on Windows 10 pro.

Comment: Is your baseline layer in Personal Geodatabase? If it is, try checking the folder name where the database is stored. According to @Midavalo's comment on [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326472/dsas-cannot-find-database-table-for-baseline-layer?rq=1), spacing in folder names creates problem for third party softwares.

Comment: Yes, baseline layer is in personal geodatabase( .mdb) , along with shoreline layer. and the name of the folder is 'BSD_DSAS_Assessment' . I used underscore in between. I am still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the DSAS manual, one solution has been proposed for this problem.

Verify that the shapefile name and “alias” are the same, otherwise DSAS will not work properly. Create a new baseline feature class and populate with the existing data as follows:

**a.** In the existing geodatabase (with the offending file), right-click and choose “create a new feature class,” name the file appropriately, and import or select the coordinate system. Most importantly, in the window with attribute selection, select “Import” and choose the original file to add all fields from the original file to the new file.

**b.** Copy and paste the old features into the new feature class. Check to make sure all the attribute files were properly carried over.